# Property-attribute synchronization

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input>

<script>
  let input = document.querySelector('input');

  // attribute => property
  input.setAttribute('id', 'id');
  alert(input.id); // id (updated)

  // property => attribute
  input.id = 'newId';
  alert(input.getAttribute('id')); // newId (updated)
</script>
```

But there are exclusions, for instance input.value synchronizes only from attribute → to property, but not back:

```
<input>

<script>
  let input = document.querySelector('input');

  // attribute => property
  input.setAttribute('value', 'text');
  alert(input.value); // text

  // NOT property => attribute
  input.value = 'newValue';
  alert(input.getAttribute('value')); // text (not updated!)
</script>
```

I am having trouble understanding why is this happening?
How do i identify these special cases?

Comment: *I am having trouble understanding why is this happening?* The value attribute serves only as a starting value, available on the DOM object via the  `defaultValue` property. The same is true for `checked`  and `selected` attributes. *How do i identify these special cases?* Read the spec, or try it out.

Comment: @connexo can you please provide a link to the related topic?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefvalue

Comment: As of now, `value`, `checked` and `selected` are the only attributes I'm aware of that have this behaviour. Might be the same for `placeholder`, haven't tested that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefchecked and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option